# How to send broadcast in a broadcastreceiver Android

Tags: static, broadcastreceiver, non-static

I have written a inner class BroadcastReceiver in a Service. And I want to send another broadcast in onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver to an Activity.

My code is:

```
public static class ServiceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.test.test");
        sendBroadcast(intent1); 
    }
}
```

But Eclipse hints "Can't make a static reference to the non-static method sendBoradcast()"

The solution I thought is to dynamically register the broadcastreceiver and remove "static" before the class.

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

You must change your code like:

```
public static class ServiceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.test.test");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent1); 
    }
}
```

Now, you are just calling `sendBrodcast()`. This way, you are using a method from your parent Class (`Service`).. This is wrong because your are accessing a non-static member from inside a Static Class.

So, use `context.sendBroadcast(intent1);` and that error would gone.